# Why doesnt this complex MySQL query work?

Tags: php, mysql, database-normalization

I have 2 tables; members and teams

members table
memberID, firstName, lastName

(firstName and lastName are fulltext indexes)

teams table
team_id, member1ID, member2ID

Here's my query

```
$sql = "SELECT a.* ";       
$sql .= "FROM teams a WHERE ";
$sql .= "a.member1ID IN (SELECT b.memberID FROM members b ";
$sql .= "WHERE MATCH(b.firstName, b.lastName) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ";
$sql .= "OR a.member2ID IN (SELECT b.memberID FROM members b ";
$sql .= "WHERE MATCH(b.firstName, b.lastName) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ";

if($year)
    $sql .= "AND a.team_y = $year ";

$sql .= "ORDER BY a.team_num ASC "; 

if($limit)      
    $sql .= "$limit";
```

This query has to be close, but its not working yet.

Im trying to build a query that will let me show me all of the teams "$q" is on.

Ex. $q=doe , Show me all teams that doe is on.

This query has to output the teams.

Comment: Please rephrase your question title because "I need help" is not a question.

Comment: It's hard to grasp the query. Show us the complete query - echo $sql;

Comment: normally there would be 3 tables : teams, members, teammembers. but since you use 2 table I would suggest you to change the way you query. By the way you forgot LIMIT word before $limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason your query doesn't work is there is a minimum length on full-text searching, which defaults to 4 characters.  "doe" would fail this match. You can increase this via variable "ft_min_word_len"
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

By the way, if you want to avoid Normalizing (which isn't always the "best" way to go), you could at least use JOIN's instead of sub-selects.. e.g. (field names renamed to save on typing)

```
select t.* from teams t
inner join members me1 on t.m1 = me1.id
inner join members me2 on t.m2 = me2.id
where MATCH(me1.fname, me1.lname, me2.fname, me2.lname) 
    AGAINST('smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Great solution! I didnt think about inner joining the same table on different columns and aliases. That worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

[Normalize your database](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html).

In your case, this would mean having a table `Team` (team_id, name, whatever else), a table `Member` (member_id, first_name, last_name), *and* a table `MemberToTeam` (member_id, team_id). In other words, move the `member1ID` and  `member2ID` into their own table.

Following this practice, apart from "improving" your database schema in the general sense, means that the query that bothers you will become trivial to write.

If you know the `member_id`:

```
SELECT team_id FROM MemberToTeam WHERE member_id = 1
```

If you search by first or last name:

```
SELECT mtt.team_id FROM Member m
LEFT JOIN MemberToTeam mtt ON m.member_id = mtt.member_id
WHERE m.first_name LIKE '%your search string here%' OR m.lastname LIKE '%your search string here%'
```

Comment: I'm not always in favor of normalization, but if there is a database that can benefit from some normalization this is it :)

Comment: ok, so if I entertain the idea of adding a 3rd table named memberToTeam, I have a few questions. What happens when a team gets edited and one of the team members changes? I dont really know how the existing memberToTeam record can be updated because the memberID has changed in the team record.

Comment: @rprincejr: If I understand you, you're assuming the Team table would have member1ID & member2ID still.. Jon's example (3 tables), this is not needed. Normalizing (moving the member1ID and member2ID fields to a new table, really depends on what you're trying to accomplish (i.e. does your team ALWAYS have 2 members ONLY). In this case, maybe your table structure is fine.). See my answer for more info