# mysql FULLTEXT query just won't work

Tags: php, mysql

Pulling my hair out, trying to figure out what's wrong here.

Create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE search_data (
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    address VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
    title VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
    time_stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (title) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

The query to search code:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('feedback')" ;
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($result) ;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
   echo "FOUND DATA- " . $row['address'] ; 
}
```

The contents of the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMgC.jpg
This doesn't work for some reason(no output). I just can't figure out why. please help.

Edit: 
confirm_query:

```
function confirm_query($result_set) 
{
    if (!$result_set) 
    {
       die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Edit2: on running the sql query manually: I get "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."
I checked for case sensitivity, but got the same thing

Comment: add : `or die(mysql_error())` to every statement that tries to connect / execute query. this way you will at least see the errors..

Comment: the confirm_query method takes care of showing any errors. I am getting no errors right now btw

Comment: what is `confirm_query()`? and are you sure you are making the query to same database connection ? one is `mysql_query(...)`, one is `mysql_query(..., $connection)`, which is which???

Comment: not very familiar with full text, but if you use a _bin charset it will be case sensitive

Comment: Have you tried running the query manually? Getting data back there would indicate there's something wrong with your PHP code. Getting nothing back in either place means your query's faulty, or you just don't have a record in your db with 'feedback' in the title.

Comment: add to Markc's statement - there may be a typo somewhere at the top of the program as well, so you wont even get to that part of the code that executes the query.. if you are running it via command line it should show you this `die`, else, if you are running it via a browser you will need to `echo` it!

Comment: I agree. There's too much annotation here, and not enough testcase!

Comment: I did a manual sql query. Got "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Comment: @user161179: I found adding a search modifier "IN BOOLEAN MODE" helped w/ returning results. See my post for complete query that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got hung up the other day on Mysql's minimum length for searching (defaults to 4 characters.. anything under 4 returns no results).  See my post here for more info:
[Why doesnt this complex MySQL query work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211749/why-doesnt-this-complex-mysql-query-work/5211863#5211863)

Update:
I found that adding the search modifier, "IN BOOLEAN MODE" allowed the query to return results with my test:

```
SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('feedback' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Good call. Damn rookie over here!

Answer (score 0):

How big is your table?  `FULLTEXT` indices aren't very effective on a small sample size.

ETA:

add a couple thousand random rows.  Make sure that they are reasonably different.  FULLTEXT won't pick up on words that are in more than 50% of the entries. Then re-run your query.  My bet is that it will work.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I considered it.  But the reason his query isn't working, isn't due to his query. It's due to the lack of rows in his table.

Comment: @dnagirl: Surely the index still _exists_, even if it's not overly effective?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: the index exists but has nothing in it.

Comment: @user161179: I've extended my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @dnagirl: Can you provide a citation for "FULLTEXT won't pick up on words that are in more than 50% of the entries"?

Comment: @dnagirl: (It's not that I don't believe you; I'm just curious about this now and would like to read more about it in the manual, having not run into this issue before.)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: the information you want is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html Search for this string: 'For very small tables, word distribution does not adequately reflect their semantic value'